# Python Dictionary with condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, conditional-statements

In this data is present for both conditions but my loop not getting the data for 2nd dict, it always terminated after first dict condition.

enter code here

```
if form and len(form) > 0:
    d1 = json.loads(form)
    d2 = list(d1.keys())
    v2 = list(d1.values())
    for x in range(len(d1)):
        if type(v2[x]) == dict and v2[x]['key']:
            selected_value = v2[x]['value']
            print("print 1")
        elif type(v2[x]) == dict and v2[x]['customer_id']:
             customer_names = v2[x]['customer_name']
             print("Print 2")
```

Comment: Fix your intentation - if `type(v2[x]) == list`, how do you expect that `type(v2[x])` will ever also be a `dict` ?

Comment: Are you saying that your dictionary fulfils the criteria for the `if` and both `elif` statements? And thus you expect it to print both your `print` statements? Because if so that is not how an `if/elif/else` block [works](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if). If you want/need to check multiple conditions separately and do something for EACH one that is fulfilled, you need to use multiple `if` clauses.

Comment: Could you add `print(d1)` after `d1 = json.loads(form)` and share the result for better understanding

Comment: @Limbo -- I am just sharing only three lines because data size is huge -

 d1 :  {'outlet': {'customer_id': '1238', 'customer_name': 'Nzmxzmm', 'field_type': 'autocomplete'}, 'coimbatore': {'key': '1', 'value': 'Demo', 'field_type': 'select'}}
 d1 :  {'outlet': {'customer_id': '1100', 'customer_name': 'Testing values', 'field_type': 'autocomplete'}, 'coimbatore': {'key': '1', 'value': 'Demo', 'field_type': 'select'}}

Answer (score 0):

You're making it much more complicated than it has to be:

```
d1 = {
     'outlet': {
         'customer_id': '1238',
         'customer_name': 'Nzmxzmm',
         'field_type': 'autocomplete'
     },
     'coimbatore': {
         'key': '1',
         'value': 'Demo',
         'field_type': 'select'
     }
 }

for item in d1.values():
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        if item.get("key"):
            selected_value = item['value']
            print("print 1")
        if item.get('customer_id'):
            customer_names = item['customer_name']
            print("Print 2")
```

Note that this will (potentially) overwrite `selected_value` and/or `customer_names` on each iteration, so you'll only get the last value for each condition. Also, if no entry matches one of the conditions, your `selected_value` and/or `customer_names` variables will not be defined, so trying to use them after the for loop will raise an error.

Comment: Your approach looks more generic thanks!! @bruno desthuilliers

Answer (score -1):

Few things:

1. Since you're checking the `type == dict`, you could add it as a common check before checking the second condition.
2. To check if the key exists in the dictionary, you could use `if key in your_dictionary`

Implementing the above two in your code, we have this:

```
    d1 = {'outlet': {'customer_id': '1238', 'customer_name': 'Nzmxzmm', 'field_type': 'autocomplete'}, 'coimbatore': {'key': '1', 'value': 'Demo', 'field_type': 'select'}}
    d2 = list(d1.keys())
    v2 = list(d1.values())
    for x in range(len(d1)):
       if type(v2[x]) == dict: # common typecheck condition
          if 'key' in v2[x]:
             selected_value = v2[x]['value']
             print(selected_value)
             print("print 1")
          elif 'customer_id' in v2[x]:
             customer_names = v2[x]['customer_name']
             print(customer_names)
             print("Print 2")
```

Results:

```
Demo
print 1
Nzmxzmm
Print 2
```

Comment: "To check if the key exists in the dictionary, you could use if key in your_dictionary.keys()" => definitly not. The correct way is `if key in dict`, which is O(1) (and very optimized). `dict.keys()` returns an iterable, so `if key in dict.keys()` is O(n). Also, dicts have a `.get(key[, default=None])` method.

Comment: And since you want to give "good practices" advises (which I totally support, but it has to be done right, right ?), the recommanded way to typecheck is to use `isinstance(obj, cls)` - unless you _really_ want to check for one single given type, in which case you want to use identity testing, ie `if type(obj) is cls`

Comment: And finally, you may want to teach the op on [the correct use of Python's `for` loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Comment: Thanks for pointing all of it out @brunodesthuilliers, I've updated my answer to use the more optimised way